# Place url of current page in a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, function, url

I am sharing the url of the current page via email by clicking a button. The URL of the current URL will be encrypted so its about 1000 characters long. How can I place the URL of current page in a hyper link in this javascript function

```
 function emailCurrentPage(){
        window.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape('document.write(<a href="window.location.href">Click here to view my link</a>) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function emailCurrentPage() {
     window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + document.title + "&body=" + escape(document.write(`<a href=${window.location.href}>Click here to view my link</a>`));
 }
```

Comment: I see, But my question was how can I write HTML into a javascript function

Comment: You should be able to just write HTML as a normal string. `\`&body=${escape('<a href="${window.location.href}">Click here to view my link</a>')}\`` (in this example I'm using backticks so I can reference variables easier and not have to do a bunch of string concats)

Comment: Updated, Joshua is right, you can use the backticks to append your link.

Comment: I see, this is just printing this now ---> <a href="${window.location.href}">Click here to view my link</a>

Comment: Odd behavior, it returning undefined in the email that is being shared, then opening a new webpage with the hyperlink, the goal is to share the link in the email